# How can I use Timer/Counter2 in Atemga128...?

Tags: c

I hava a trouble with using Timer/Counter 02
I use Atmega128 8bit Proccessor and It has 16MHz crystal.
I know how to use Timer00, but I can't use Timer02

I learned that timer 00 and 02 are so similar.

below, There is my short code..
Please see the code.. I need your help..

thanks

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/delay.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

/*COUNT VARIABLE, SWITCH VARIABLE*/
unsigned int cnt_LED= 0; //LED TIMER0 COUNT 
unsigned int cnt_FND= 0; // FND TIMER2 COUNT
unsigned short FND_sw=0;
/********************************/


/*Function List*/
void LED();
void FND_TURN_ON();
/***************/



/**** LED TIMER2 ****/
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) // 0.002*1500= 3s
{
    TCNT2 = 0x82;
    if(++cnt_LED ==1500) {
       PORTA = 0x00;
       cnt_LED = 0;
    }
}
/*******************/

int main()
{
    sei();
    LED();
    while(1)
    {

    }

}
    void LED()
    {
        /*LED Register*/
        DDRA = 0xff;
        TCCR2 = 0x06; //B 0000 0101
        TCNT2 = 0x82;

        /*************/

    PORTA = 0xff; //led on
        TIMSK = 0x40;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you switch the led in the interrupt routine . I think your intention is to toggle it.

Secondly the counter has to be volatile.